# VmRSS used to only about 25%, yet oom-killer strikes

Tags: linux, mysql, memory, oom, oom-killer

I have a dedicated MySQL server equipped with 128 GB RAM. MySQL recently gets killed by the oom-killer, although MySQL is configured to use 95 GB in the worst case. In my research I came across this:

```
# cat /proc/11895/status
Name:   mysqld
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   11895
Pid:    11895
PPid:   24530
TracerPid:      0
Uid:    27      27      27      27
Gid:    27      27      27      27
Utrace: 0
FDSize: 1024
Groups: 27
VmPeak: 72188044 kB
VmSize: 72122508 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmHWM:  33294036 kB
VmRSS:  32829668 kB
VmData: 72076496 kB
VmStk:        88 kB
VmExe:     11800 kB
VmLib:      3608 kB
VmPTE:     73388 kB
VmSwap:  4139376 kB
Threads:        59
```

I'm wondering, why is the VmHWM and VmRSS at only around 33 GB whereas on another server (also a slave to the same master, configured almost the same (except for buffer pool), except, that it has 256 GB RAM), the output is as follows:

```
# cat /proc/51298/status
Name:   mysqld
State:  S (sleeping)
Tgid:   51298
Pid:    51298
PPid:   50443
TracerPid:      0
Uid:    27      27      27      27
Gid:    27      27      27      27
Utrace: 0
FDSize: 2048
Groups: 27
VmPeak: 243701128 kB
VmSize: 239628932 kB
VmLck:         0 kB
VmHWM:  209331200 kB
VmRSS:  205515868 kB
VmData: 239582156 kB
VmStk:        88 kB
VmExe:     11800 kB
VmLib:      3608 kB
VmPTE:    409600 kB
VmSwap:        0 kB
Threads:        281
```

Here the memory is used to about 80%, whereas on the oom-killed server it's only about 25% (note, that these values were observed shortly before the oom-killer striked again). What could be the reason? There is no competing process. And what can I do about it?

EDIT: Here's what dmesg tells me:

```
mysqld invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0
mysqld cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0-1
Pid: 11902, comm: mysqld Not tainted 2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64 #1
Call Trace:
 [<ffffffff810d6d71>] ? cpuset_print_task_mems_allowed+0x91/0xb0
 [<ffffffff8112a570>] ? dump_header+0x90/0x1b0
 [<ffffffff81232c5c>] ? security_real_capable_noaudit+0x3c/0x70
 [<ffffffff8112a9f2>] ? oom_kill_process+0x82/0x2a0
 [<ffffffff8112a931>] ? select_bad_process+0xe1/0x120
 [<ffffffff8112ae30>] ? out_of_memory+0x220/0x3c0
 [<ffffffff8113780c>] ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x93c/0x950
 [<ffffffffa00bd560>] ? ext4_get_block+0x0/0x120 [ext4]
 [<ffffffff8117021a>] ? alloc_pages_current+0xaa/0x110
 [<ffffffff81127967>] ? __page_cache_alloc+0x87/0x90
 [<ffffffff8112734e>] ? find_get_page+0x1e/0xa0
 [<ffffffff81128907>] ? filemap_fault+0x1a7/0x500
 [<ffffffff81151ec4>] ? __do_fault+0x54/0x530
 [<ffffffff81152497>] ? handle_pte_fault+0xf7/0xb20
 [<ffffffff810672e0>] ? wake_up_state+0x10/0x20
 [<ffffffff810b4e7c>] ? wake_futex+0x3c/0x60
 [<ffffffff81153159>] ? handle_mm_fault+0x299/0x3d0
 [<ffffffff81066053>] ? perf_event_task_sched_out+0x33/0x70
 [<ffffffff8104f156>] ? __do_page_fault+0x146/0x500
 [<ffffffff810672b0>] ? default_wake_function+0x0/0x20
 [<ffffffff811dfc50>] ? timeout_func+0x0/0x20
 [<ffffffff8153eb4e>] ? do_page_fault+0x3e/0xa0
 [<ffffffff8153bef5>] ? page_fault+0x25/0x30
Mem-Info:
Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
CPU    2: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
CPU    3: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
CPU    4: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
CPU    5: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
CPU    6: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
CPU    7: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
CPU    8: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
CPU    9: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
CPU   10: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
CPU   11: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu:
CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    4: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    5: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    6: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    7: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    8: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    9: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU   10: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU   11: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Node 0 Normal per-cpu:
CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    4: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    5: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    6: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    7: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    8: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    9: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU   10: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU   11: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Node 1 Normal per-cpu:
CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  29
CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  30
CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    4: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    5: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    6: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  15
CPU    7: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    8: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU    9: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU   10: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
CPU   11: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
active_anon:8256706 inactive_anon:760868 isolated_anon:0
 active_file:280 inactive_file:51 isolated_file:0
 unevictable:0 dirty:166 writeback:0 unstable:0
 free:87964 slab_reclaimable:6774 slab_unreclaimable:11217
 mapped:138 shmem:2 pagetables:21060 bounce:0
Node 0 DMA free:15736kB min:8kB low:8kB high:12kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15340kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2955 64565 64565
Node 0 DMA32 free:248508kB min:2060kB low:2572kB high:3088kB active_anon:1292624kB inactive_anon:388708kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:3026080kB mlocked:0kB dirty:16kB writeback:0kB mapped:76kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:5776kB slab_unreclaimable:556kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:1824kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 61610 61610
Node 0 Normal free:42672kB min:42960kB low:53700kB high:64440kB active_anon:14828712kB inactive_anon:1241992kB active_file:244kB inactive_file:476kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:63088640kB mlocked:0kB dirty:20kB writeback:0kB mapped:8kB shmem:8kB slab_reclaimable:11740kB slab_unreclaimable:27576kB kernel_stack:5568kB pagetables:42220kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:1136 all_unreclaimable? yes
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Node 1 Normal free:44940kB min:45076kB low:56344kB high:67612kB active_anon:16905488kB inactive_anon:1412772kB active_file:880kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:66191360kB mlocked:0kB dirty:628kB writeback:0kB mapped:468kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:9580kB slab_unreclaimable:16736kB kernel_stack:1472kB pagetables:40196kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Node 0 DMA: 2*4kB 0*8kB 1*16kB 1*32kB 1*64kB 0*128kB 1*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB 1*2048kB 3*4096kB = 15736kB
Node 0 DMA32: 1410*4kB 1324*8kB 1136*16kB 941*32kB 659*64kB 332*128kB 162*256kB 51*512kB 25*1024kB 1*2048kB 1*4096kB = 248520kB
Node 0 Normal: 1169*4kB 619*8kB 477*16kB 304*32kB 132*64kB 48*128kB 8*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 43628kB
Node 1 Normal: 939*4kB 637*8kB 446*16kB 296*32kB 165*64kB 53*128kB 4*256kB 1*512kB 1*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 45364kB
60924 total pagecache pages
60506 pages in swap cache
Swap cache stats: add 16616696, delete 16556190, find 18336133/18806499
Free swap  = 0kB
Total swap = 4194300kB
33554431 pages RAM
527380 pages reserved
497 pages shared
9240689 pages non-shared
[ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss cpu oom_adj oom_score_adj name
[ 1010]     0  1010     2842        1   2     -17         -1000 udevd
[ 3086]     0  3086    23289       42   8     -17         -1000 auditd
[ 3174]     0  3174    16556       26   1     -17         -1000 sshd
[ 3253]     0  3253    20217       24   2       0             0 master
[ 3265]     0  3265    29216       22   0       0             0 crond
[ 3474]     0  3474   249065      355   0       0             0 dsm_sa_datamgrd
[ 3684]     0  3684    73206       86   1       0             0 dsm_sa_eventmgr
[ 3685]     0  3685   115300        9   0       0             0 dsm_sa_datamgrd
[ 3712]     0  3712   109424      428   7       0             0 dsm_sa_snmpd
[ 3757]     0  3757   159830       53   2       0             0 dsm_om_shrsvcd
[ 3781]     0  3781     1016        2   2       0             0 mingetty
[ 3783]     0  3783     1016        2   8       0             0 mingetty
[ 3789]     0  3789     1016        2   9       0             0 mingetty
[ 3795]     0  3795     1016        2  11       0             0 mingetty
[ 3798]     0  3798     1016        2   6       0             0 mingetty
[ 3800]     0  3800     1016        2   2       0             0 mingetty
[ 6104]     0  6104     2841        1   0     -17         -1000 udevd
[ 6106]     0  6106     2841        1   0     -17         -1000 udevd
[24530]     0 24530    26550        7   1       0             0 mysqld_safe
[31635]     0 31635    80599      197   0       0             0 bacula-fd
[38121]     0 38121    55171    26624   0       0             0 puppetd
[ 4546]     0  4546    62368     1465   0       0             0 rsyslogd
[19221]     0 19221     1530        1   3       0             0 collectdmon
[19222]     0 19222   443447     3024   4       0             0 collectd
[ 1460]   500  1460   125934       60   1       0             0 icinga2
[ 1473]   500  1473   688892     1098   1       0             0 icinga2
[18124]    89 18124    20280       19   0       0             0 qmgr
[41035]     0 41035    25232       27   2       0             0 rhnsd
[41116]     0 41116    52038      401   0       0             0 osad
[11895]    27 11895 18030627  8921592   1       0             0 mysqld
[41068]     0 41068    24993      253   2       0             0 sshd
[41070]     0 41070    25142      405   0       0             0 sshd
[14243]     0 14243    24993      244   0       0             0 sshd
[14245]     0 14245    27110      120   1       0             0 bash
[22904]     0 22904    24993      253   2       0             0 sshd
[22906]     0 22906    27108      124   2       0             0 bash
[25586]    38 25586     7684      154   0       0             0 ntpd
[58468]    89 58468    20237      221   1       0             0 pickup
Out of memory: Kill process 11895 (mysqld) score 292 or sacrifice child
Killed process 11895, UID 27, (mysqld) total-vm:72122508kB, anon-rss:35686344kB, file-rss:48kB
```

Output of `cat /proc/self/mountinfo`:

```
16 21 0:3 / /proc rw,relatime - proc proc rw
17 21 0:0 / /sys rw,relatime - sysfs sysfs rw
18 21 0:5 / /dev rw,relatime - devtmpfs devtmpfs rw,size=66042096k,nr_inodes=16510524,mode=755
19 18 0:11 / /dev/pts rw,relatime - devpts devpts rw,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000
20 18 0:16 / /dev/shm rw,relatime - tmpfs tmpfs rw
21 1 253:0 / / rw,relatime - ext4 /dev/mapper/vg_ods055-lv_root rw,barrier=1,data=ordered
22 16 0:15 / /proc/bus/usb rw,relatime - usbfs /proc/bus/usb rw
23 21 8:1 / /boot rw,relatime - ext4 /dev/sda1 rw,barrier=1,data=ordered
24 21 253:3 / /home rw,relatime - ext4 /dev/mapper/vg_ods055-lv_home rw,barrier=1,data=ordered
25 21 253:2 / /var/lib/mysql rw,relatime - ext4 /dev/mapper/vg_ods055_mysql-mysql_data rw,barrier=1,data=ordered
26 16 0:17 / /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc rw,relatime - binfmt_misc none rw
```

Output of `lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
tcp_diag                1041  0
inet_diag               8735  1 tcp_diag
vfat                   10584  0
fat                    54992  1 vfat
usb_storage            49228  0
mpt3sas               191659  1
mpt2sas               189883  1
scsi_transport_sas     35588  2 mpt3sas,mpt2sas
raid_class              4388  2 mpt3sas,mpt2sas
mptctl                 31785  1
mptbase                93647  1 mptctl
dell_rbu                9414  0
ipv6                  335525  144
ipmi_devintf            7729  2
sg                     29318  0
joydev                 10480  0
power_meter             9009  0
acpi_ipmi               3745  1 power_meter
ipmi_si                44751  2 acpi_ipmi
ipmi_msghandler        38701  3 ipmi_devintf,acpi_ipmi,ipmi_si
iTCO_wdt                7115  0
iTCO_vendor_support     3056  1 iTCO_wdt
tg3                   161289  0
ptp                     9614  1 tg3
pps_core               10690  1 ptp
dcdbas                  8707  0
sb_edac                17888  0
edac_core              46645  3 sb_edac
lpc_ich                12963  0
mfd_core                1895  1 lpc_ich
shpchp                 29130  0
ext4                  378683  4
jbd2                   93252  1 ext4
mbcache                 8193  1 ext4
sd_mod                 37030  5
crc_t10dif              1209  1 sd_mod
sr_mod                 15049  0
cdrom                  39085  1 sr_mod
megaraid_sas          109375  5
wmi                     6287  0
ahci                   42738  0
dm_mirror              14384  0
dm_region_hash         12085  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                  9930  2 dm_mirror,dm_region_hash
dm_mod                 99168  14 dm_mirror,dm_log
```

---

```
# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_ods055-lv_root
                       50G  9.7G   37G  21% /
tmpfs                  63G     0   63G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             477M   57M  395M  13% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_ods055-lv_home
                       81G   56M   77G   1% /home
/dev/mapper/vg_ods055_mysql-mysql_data
                      1.1T  700G  344G  68% /var/lib/mysql
```

Output of `cat /proc/meminfo`:

```
MemTotal:       132108204 kB
MemFree:          380404 kB
Buffers:          214256 kB
Cached:         16000720 kB
SwapCached:        22964 kB
Active:         26156736 kB
Inactive:        9329756 kB
Active(anon):   16971328 kB
Inactive(anon):  2300216 kB
Active(file):    9185408 kB
Inactive(file):  7029540 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       4194300 kB
SwapFree:        4039224 kB
Dirty:               816 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:      19261368 kB
Mapped:            17860 kB
Shmem:                20 kB
Slab:             662020 kB
SReclaimable:     617680 kB
SUnreclaim:        44340 kB
KernelStack:        7008 kB
PageTables:        43768 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    22869968 kB
Committed_AS:   69472720 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      484276 kB
VmallocChunk:   34291771192 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:  16736256 kB
HugePages_Total:   46268
HugePages_Free:    46268
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:        5056 kB
DirectMap2M:     2045952 kB
DirectMap1G:    132120576 kB
```

Output of `cat /proc/zoneinfo`:

```
Node 0, zone      DMA
  pages free     3934
        min      2
        low      2
        high     3
        scanned  0
        spanned  4095
        present  3835
    nr_free_pages 3934
    nr_inactive_anon 0
    nr_active_anon 0
    nr_inactive_file 0
    nr_active_file 0
    nr_unevictable 0
    nr_mlock     0
    nr_anon_pages 0
    nr_mapped    0
    nr_file_pages 0
    nr_dirty     0
    nr_writeback 0
    nr_slab_reclaimable 0
    nr_slab_unreclaimable 0
    nr_page_table_pages 0
    nr_kernel_stack 0
    nr_unstable  0
    nr_bounce    0
    nr_vmscan_write 0
    nr_writeback_temp 0
    nr_isolated_anon 0
    nr_isolated_file 0
    nr_shmem     0
    numa_hit     1
    numa_miss    0
    numa_foreign 0
    numa_interleave 0
    numa_local   0
    numa_other   1
    nr_anon_transparent_hugepages 0
        protection: (0, 2955, 64565, 64565)
  pagesets
    cpu: 0
              count: 0
              high:  0
              batch: 1
  vm stats threshold: 8
    cpu: 1
              count: 0
              high:  0
              batch: 1
  vm stats threshold: 8
    cpu: 2
              count: 0
              high:  0
              batch: 1
  vm stats threshold: 8
    cpu: 3
              count: 0
              high:  0
              batch: 1
  vm stats threshold: 8
    cpu: 4
              count: 0
              high:  0
              batch: 1
  vm stats threshold: 8
    cpu: 5
              count: 0
              high:  0
              batch: 1
  vm stats threshold: 8
    cpu: 6
              count: 0
              high:  0
              batch: 1
  vm stats threshold: 8
    cpu: 7
              count: 0
              high:  0
              batch: 1
  vm stats threshold: 8
    cpu: 8
              count: 0
              high:  0
              batch: 1
  vm stats threshold: 8
    cpu: 9
              count: 0
              high:  0
              batch: 1
  vm stats threshold: 8
    cpu: 10
              count: 0
              high:  0
              batch: 1
  vm stats threshold: 8
    cpu: 11
              count: 0
              high:  0
              batch: 1
  vm stats threshold: 8
  all_unreclaimable: 1
  prev_priority:     12
  start_pfn:         1
  inactive_ratio:    1
Node 0, zone    DMA32
  pages free     62344
        min      515
        low      643
        high     772
        scanned  0
        spanned  1044480
        present  756520
    nr_free_pages 62344
    nr_inactive_anon 86498
    nr_active_anon 226241
    nr_inactive_file 14165
    nr_active_file 14186
    nr_unevictable 0
    nr_mlock     0
    nr_anon_pages 5484
    nr_mapped    4
    nr_file_pages 28412
    nr_dirty     0
    nr_writeback 0
    nr_slab_reclaimable 80093
    nr_slab_unreclaimable 251
    nr_page_table_pages 250
    nr_kernel_stack 0
    nr_unstable  0
    nr_bounce    0
    nr_vmscan_write 2329633
    nr_writeback_temp 0
    nr_isolated_anon 0
    nr_isolated_file 0
    nr_shmem     0
    numa_hit     30968949
    numa_miss    12412436
    numa_foreign 0
    numa_interleave 0
    numa_local   30968183
    numa_other   12413202
    nr_anon_transparent_hugepages 600
        protection: (0, 0, 61610, 61610)
  pagesets
    cpu: 0
              count: 21
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 48
    cpu: 1
              count: 0
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 48
    cpu: 2
              count: 75
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 48
    cpu: 3
              count: 0
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 48
    cpu: 4
              count: 199
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 48
    cpu: 5
              count: 0
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 48
    cpu: 6
              count: 16
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 48
    cpu: 7
              count: 0
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 48
    cpu: 8
              count: 24
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 48
    cpu: 9
              count: 0
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 48
    cpu: 10
              count: 167
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 48
    cpu: 11
              count: 0
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 48
  all_unreclaimable: 0
  prev_priority:     12
  start_pfn:         4096
  inactive_ratio:    4
Node 0, zone   Normal
  pages free     13426
        min      10740
        low      13425
        high     16110
        scanned  0
        spanned  15990784
        present  15772160
    nr_free_pages 13426
    nr_inactive_anon 277373
    nr_active_anon 2623458
    nr_inactive_file 422756
    nr_active_file 652474
    nr_unevictable 0
    nr_mlock     0
    nr_anon_pages 304740
    nr_mapped    2764
    nr_file_pages 1079208
    nr_dirty     32
    nr_writeback 0
    nr_slab_reclaimable 46034
    nr_slab_unreclaimable 6793
    nr_page_table_pages 6298
    nr_kernel_stack 334
    nr_unstable  0
    nr_bounce    0
    nr_vmscan_write 8578494
    nr_writeback_temp 0
    nr_isolated_anon 0
    nr_isolated_file 0
    nr_shmem     5
    numa_hit     788900341
    numa_miss    44641935
    numa_foreign 291882873
    numa_interleave 678929
    numa_local   788587089
    numa_other   44955187
    nr_anon_transparent_hugepages 5067
        protection: (0, 0, 0, 0)
  pagesets
    cpu: 0
              count: 37
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
    cpu: 1
              count: 1
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
    cpu: 2
              count: 30
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
    cpu: 3
              count: 3
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
    cpu: 4
              count: 114
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
    cpu: 5
              count: 0
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
    cpu: 6
              count: 161
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
    cpu: 7
              count: 0
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
    cpu: 8
              count: 85
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
    cpu: 9
              count: 0
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
    cpu: 10
              count: 184
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
    cpu: 11
              count: 0
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
  all_unreclaimable: 0
  prev_priority:     12
  start_pfn:         1048576
  inactive_ratio:    24
Node 1, zone   Normal
  pages free     15668
        min      11269
        low      14086
        high     16903
        scanned  0
        spanned  16777216
        present  16547840
    nr_free_pages 15668
    nr_inactive_anon 210225
    nr_active_anon 1405678
    nr_inactive_file 1312467
    nr_active_file 1626153
    nr_unevictable 0
    nr_mlock     0
    nr_anon_pages 332657
    nr_mapped    1691
    nr_file_pages 2940312
    nr_dirty     97
    nr_writeback 0
    nr_slab_reclaimable 27961
    nr_slab_unreclaimable 4145
    nr_page_table_pages 4417
    nr_kernel_stack 104
    nr_unstable  0
    nr_bounce    0
    nr_vmscan_write 7441636
    nr_writeback_temp 0
    nr_isolated_anon 0
    nr_isolated_file 0
    nr_shmem     0
    numa_hit     568448792
    numa_miss    291882873
    numa_foreign 57054371
    numa_interleave 678973
    numa_local   567389682
    numa_other   292941983
    nr_anon_transparent_hugepages 2505
        protection: (0, 0, 0, 0)
  pagesets
    cpu: 0
              count: 44
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
    cpu: 1
              count: 98
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
    cpu: 2
              count: 171
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
    cpu: 3
              count: 28
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
    cpu: 4
              count: 55
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
    cpu: 5
              count: 32
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
    cpu: 6
              count: 100
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
    cpu: 7
              count: 204
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
    cpu: 8
              count: 30
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
    cpu: 9
              count: 154
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
    cpu: 10
              count: 30
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
    cpu: 11
              count: 91
              high:  186
              batch: 31
  vm stats threshold: 80
  all_unreclaimable: 0
  prev_priority:     12
  start_pfn:         17039360
  inactive_ratio:    25
```

Comment: Theres insufficient information to make a diagnosis here. Can you supply the entirity of the oom-killer log output, along with the task dump it produces?

Comment: @MatthewIfe Thanks for having a look. I'm relatively inexperienced, hope what I posted is what you're looking for. Let me know, if you need more information.

Comment: Something is not right here. Is this a virtual machine and if so what variant?

Comment: No, it's not a virtual machine. @MatthewIfe What makes you think, that something's not right?

Comment: Can you provide the output of `cat /proc/self/mountinfo`, `df -h` and `lsmod`? Something is using up the memory that and not accounting for it.

Comment: @MatthewIfe Provided the info you requested, though it may be hard to find something suspicious now. At the moment the memory looks good. It might take several days now until the memory situation is serious again.

Comment: If you can provide the output of `cat /proc/meminfo` and `cat /proc/zoneinfo` too that would be helpful. If you have not rebooted the system since the issue whatever is using up the memory may still be present.

Comment: Also, this is one case where the OOM killer is a really, really bad idea - it's killing the database process on your database server.  IMO for servers, the OOM killer should be disabled - it'll kill the processes that are the very reason you have the server.  Like here.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I disagree, there is something underlying going on thats causing this problem. If you count up all the pages recorded they dont match anywhere near what it thought was free. You are not fixing the problem disabling oom killer.

Comment: @MatthewIfe A server should never overcommit memory, obviating the need for the OOM killer.  I like my servers to *always* work, and not have the OS lie to a process about available memory that may not really be available.

Comment: @MatthewIfe Provided what was requested. And no, I've not rebooted the server. Thanks again so much for your effort.

Comment: @AndrewHenle linux memory over-commitment policy is a separate topic really to this issue. In the case above here you'll still have problems disabling it due to wacky ENOMEM handling in applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
HugePages_Total:   46268
HugePages_Free:    46268
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:        5056 kB
```

You have enabled some huge page assignments and aren't using them. These hugepages have taken up a big slice of your memory. Disable this assignment.

Run

```
sysctl -w vm.nr_hugepages=0
```

Then check `/etc/sysctl.conf` and remove the assignment you have set.

This should free up about 90GiB of memory you are wasting.

Comment: Oh my god, that's it! A colleague was experimenting there a bit and didn't revert all changes it seems. Thank you so much. Was looking around for 2 weeks now. Thank you. If only I could upvote twice :)

Comment: Gave credit to you in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/365178/67279).